# Flagging dialog wrongly claims flag had already been raised before

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, flags, flag-history

I believe I have encountered a new bug related to flagging. I was just reviewing new posts and flagged some answers as "not being an answer". I was surprised to see that in each of these cases, when the flag reason dialog opened, the message read that I had already flagged that post as "very low quality". This is definitely not true.

Example:

I reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678267/python-errno-8-exec-format-error-app-venv-bin-python/67436473#67436473) with the title *Python [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/app/.venv/bin/python'*

ad this dialog opened:

[image]

at the time, this was definitely not true:

[image]

Since it happened 3 times in a row, I assume this is a bug. However, I could not reproduce it with *any* attempt to raise a flag, so I guess it might happen with posts where *someone else* has already raised a flag?

Comment: ^ and there's a MSE dupe linked in that other Q.

Comment: @JeanneDark; Yes, it does. I searched but did not find that one. So this can be closed as a duplicate I guess. Sorry.

Comment: It is happened with me more than five times.