# I flagged a post as VLQ accidentally and I can't retract it -- why?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I was trying to flag [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465421/i-am-trying-to-execute-python-code-code-from-this) as VLQ but it didn't let me saying "You don't have the permissions to use this type of flag" or something similar to this. I got surprised as I could flag posts as VLQ earlier. I voted to close and moved on to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465441/how-to-find-the-largest-area-in-a-given-matrix-and-return-its-position-boundries) for testing. I flagged it as VLQ and it actually worked.

- How do I undo the flag? I tried to retract my flag, (I believe I could do this in the past) but there is no such option. I don't want to get a flag ban.
- What could be the reason why I couldn't flag the first post?

Comment: For 1) click the 'flag' link again and there should be an option to revoke the flag

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought the same at first. But it's not the case. When I click 'flag' link it opens the same pop up without 'VLQ' option and there is only one button called `Flag Question`

Comment: Hmm, weird, I just tried flagging a question as VLQ and it's also gone from the flag dialog without any option to revoke. Possibly a bug...

Comment: @AndrewT. I think Kyle might have broken it when he fixed the ["You have already raised this flag"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407495/flagging-dialog-wrongly-claims-flag-had-already-been-raised-before) bug

Comment: @Vega No, I was checking new questions normally.

Comment: @AndrewT. I believe the VLQ option (on questions) disappears if the post has a positive vote score. Just checked on a few Meta.SE posts (where I don't have close-vote privilege) and that seems to be the case. Not sure if that's befuddling the issue here, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole This seems to always have been the case. The option to flag as VLQ vanishes if the question or answer received an upvote (not sure it depends on upvote or score) or if it's a bit older (I don't know how old it has to be exactly to no longer be flaggable as VLQ). These are the differences to the NAA flag (apart from being marked helpful in case of an edit after the grace period).

Comment: @JeanneDark Indeed. But I was just trying to (possibly) clarify the issue reported by Andrew. Otherwise, I can't reproduce that aspect (on SO, anyway) - I see the VLQ as a flag option on zero-scored (new) questions. Maybe I just added a new level of befuddlement.

Comment: @AdrianMole perhaps my comment wasn't that clear, sorry. I did flag a question that's showing the VLQ option, and it consumed my daily flag quota and shown "pending" on my flag history, but when I open the flag dialog again on the same question, I can't revoke the flag.

Comment: This should be retagged as [bug] but the question needs to be reworded. I didn't want to make too many changes to the post.

Comment: @41686d6564 I also think that this is a bug. If you can think of a way to reword the question, feel free to do. I understand my second question can be answered with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374977/where-is-low-quality-flag) but I can't find a good way to include it in the edit and rephrase the question.

Comment: see also feature request at MSE: [Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283357/165773)

Comment: same feature request here at MSO: [Unable to retract VLQ flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333569/839601)

Comment: Both of your questions appear to be answered by the linked duplicate: Both posts quickly entered the Triage queue: The first within 44 seconds of the question being posted; the second immediately upon you raising your VLQ flag (which, presumably, caused the VLQ option to be hidden, resulting in you not being permitted to retract your flag from the flag dialog). If you think it's a bug, or want it to change, then you'd need to create a *new* question which is a straight bug report or feature request (i.e. not asking "why", as was the *primary* thing you asked here), but it would be a duplicate.

Comment: "meh" (w.r.t posting a new question). I just added the above question found by @gnat to the duplicate-target list.

Comment: @Makyen At first, I didn't realized that dupe was answering both questions. Now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Asocia Just FYI: I've added an additional answer to [Unable to retract VLQ flag](/a/407550/3773011), which links to a newer userscript by [Samuel Liew](//stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew), [Flag Retractor](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/FlagRetractor.user.js) ([install](//github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/FlagRetractor.user.js)), which does basically the same thing as the no longer available userscript mentioned in the other answer: allow you to retract flags from your "Flags raised by <user>" page. It can be used as a workaround.